# IOS 8 Keyboard Support for Different Languages

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a application supporting gujrati and english languages.
In ios 9 there is a support for Gujrati language on the keyboard,but same is not the case with iOS 8.

Can anyone please suggest how can i make keyboard in iOS 8 show support for gujrati language

Comment: If there's no support for gujarati in iOS 8 there's nothing you can do. You could implement your own keyboard, but that would probably take a few months. Best thing is to show an alert to users using that language and iOS 8 to update to iOS 9.

Comment: Yes, @EmilioPelaez but i still want to give support maybe i will try implementing custom keyboard.